# Script simply doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code here which simply refuses to work. I have another javascript code that works with this, and it has those array variables defined (text mostly). Can somebody see what am I doing wrong here?

```
    var ran_num = new Array[37]

for (i = 1; i < 39; i++){
    document.write('<span id=' + '"pitanje' + i + '"' + '>' + '</span>')
    ran_num[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
    if (i != 3 && i != 4 && i != 29){
        if(ran_num[i] < 30){
            document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje1[i]
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje2[i]
        }
    }
    else if(i == 3){
        document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje3
    }
    else if (i == 4) {
        if  (ran_num[i] < 30){
            document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje4_1
        }
        if  (ran_num[i] < 60){
            document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje4_2
        }
            else{
                document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje4_3
            }
    }
    else if (i == 29){
        document.getElementById("pitanje"+i).innerHTML = pitanje29
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the console -> _Uncaught TypeError: Array[37] is not a function_

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console? In what way exactly does it not work? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Well, it should loop 38 times and create <span> elements and then according to the current integer, display inner HTML of the span from the variable. SO if i = 1, then the span should be created and its inner HTML should be the content of the variable pitanje1[1] OR pitanje2[1].
BUT Nothing is displayed, not even spans, because either loop doesn't start OR functions refuse to work..

Comment: OK.  Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: Yes I did, and I have first: "Uncaught ReferenceError: pitanje1 is not defined" and second: "Uncaught TypeError: Array[37] is not a function".
But I defined all the variable arrays AND each array of variable

Comment: Those errors are the problem. The only array declaration I see is the incorrect one for `ran_num`, which should just be `var ran_num = [];` - there's not much point in using the Array constructor explicitly because there's no bounds checking.

Comment: Oh my God. So that was the problem, I did not properly declared an array...
Well can you in short explain the difference between my declaration and yours?
I thank you so much, It finally works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your array initialization is not right, try replace your first line with this

```
var ran_num = new Array(37); // this creates an aray with 37 elements that are undefined
```

you can populate your array with values like this before you use it in your for loop:

```
for( var i = 0; i < ran_num.length; i++) {
  ran_num[i] = i;
}
```